# Подскажите как добавить у последних категорий тег а в цикле foreach многоуровнего массива Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

подскажите пожалуйста как добавить всем последним категориям тег а в цикле foreach многоуровнего массива Laravel

сейчас у меня имеется вот такой код

```html
@foreach($categories as $category)

<li class="parent">
    @if($categories->last() === $category)
        {{ $category->name }}
    @else
       <a href="#">{{ $category->name }}</a>
    @endif

    <ul style="display: none">
        <li class="parent">
            @include('cabinet.adverts.create._categories', ['categories' => $category->children])
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>

@endforeach
```

вот что на выходе

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://snipp.ru/view/107

Comment: `$category->children->count()` должен вернуть кол-во детей, проверяете на их наличие и добавляйте или нет тег, по условию `$category->children->count() > 0`

Comment: Это то что нужно! Спасибо вам огромное!